# SASS Compiler Custom Rules / Exceptions

Tags: php, css, ruby, sass

I'm writing Sass/CSS for a software that has it's own html/css templating system. The outputted CSS files are read and any variables inside are converted into the correct values when the templates are built. The variables look like

**{theme="my_var_key"};**

I want to be able to code in Sass but still make use of the the software's custom variables on the outputted css file.

**Is it possible to add custom rules / exceptions to the sass compiler so that the above variable is compiled as is?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output solid strings in SASS by using `#{$variable}`

```
$var: '{theme="my_var_key"}';
body{
  color: #{$var};
}
```

Which outputs:

```
body {
  color: {theme="my_var_key"};
}
```

This can also be used in class or ID names. E.g: `.#{$var}` outputs `.{theme="my_var_key"}`

Comment: What an amazing tip. Thanks :-)